# Script or command to cut words to newline in a text file

Tags: shell, unix

Say I have a text file (text1.txt) containing the following content :

```
TAG 97
//S211130000059564  SE0000273294
//SE0000112724
MDGF 348
```

For a line starting with // if there is a second word, I want to have that word printed in the next line, so the above file text1.txt will become :

```
TAG 97
//S211130000059564  
SE0000273294
//SE0000112724
MDGF 348
```

Can any one help me on this,Pls..

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -pe 's@^(//\S+)\s+(\S+)@$1\n$2@' file.txt
```

or using GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r 's@^(//\S+)\s+(\S+)@\1\n\2@' file.txt
```

(thanks [steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751863/steve))

**OUTPUT**

```
TAG 97
//S211130000059564
SE0000273294
//SE0000112724
MDGF 348
```

**short EXPLANATIONS**

- I use substitution mechanism both in `perl` & `sed`, they're both do the same
- I use `@` as delimiter (an arbitrary choice, pick up any character you'd like)

Comment: +1 You could also use `GNU sed`: `sed -r 's@^(//\S+)\s+(\S+)@\1\n\2@' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '/^\/\// && NF == 2 { print $1 ORS $2; next }1' file
```

Results:

```
TAG 97
//S211130000059564  
SE0000273294
//SE0000112724
MDGF 348
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if($0~/\/\// && $2)print $1"\n"$2; else print}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
TAG 97
//S211130000059564  SE0000273294
//SE0000112724
MDGF 348
> awk '{if($0~/\/\// && $2)print $1"\n"$2; else print}' temp
TAG 97
//S211130000059564
SE0000273294
//SE0000112724
MDGF 348
>
```